# How can I make preset json data ready to be used in my highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, highcharts

currently in my snippet my chart shows all data in var json. I want to make it so when I press a button (1 month) it only shows data in the last month (30/31days).

I want to start from today's date and work backwards 1 month. If the the value of the KEY "P" in my var json falls between today and 1 month display the data in the chart. If it doesn't just ignore it.

I will want to eventually at a later date want add more pre sets like 1day, 1 week etc.

```js
var json = [{
  "c": "CHINA",
  "d": "GREAT BRITAIN",
  "e": "*PI",
  "f": "NGB",
  "g": "CN",
  "i": "GB",
  "j": "9PIO5090196",
  "k": "2PIO5090420",
  "l": "WL150802C/D",
  "m": "NB15080682",
  "n": 9,
  "o": 6,
  "P": "2015-09-22T17:40",
  "N": "2015-10-21",
  "O": "2015-10-22T17:40"
}, {
  "c": "CHINA",
  "d": "GREAT BRITAIN",
  "e": "*PI",
  "f": "NGB",
  "g": "CN",
  "i": "GB",
  "j": "9PIO5090196",
  "k": "2PIO5090420",
  "l": "WL150802C/D",
  "m": "NB15080682",
  "n": 9,
  "o": 6,
  "P": "2015-09-22T17:40",
  "N": "2015-10-21",
  "O": "2015-04-22T17:40"
}, {
  "c": "CHINA",
  "d": "GREAT BRITAIN",
  "e": "*PI",
  "f": "NGB",
  "g": "CN",
  "i": "GB",
  "j": "9PIO5090196",
  "k": "2PIO5090420",
  "l": "WL150802C/D",
  "m": "NB15080682",
  "n": 9,
  "o": 6,
  "P": "2015-01-22T17:40",
  "N": "2015-10-21",
  "O": "2015-09-22T17:40"
}]

// Pie Chart import/export
var importcount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 5 || v.o == 6 || v.o == 1);
});
importcount = importcount.length;

var exportcount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 2 || v.o == 3 || v.o == 4);
});
exportcount = exportcount.length;

console.log(exportcount);
console.log(importcount);


// IMPORT AIR 
var importaircount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 5);
});
importaircount = importaircount.length;

// IMPORT SEA 
var importseacount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 6);
});
importseacount = importseacount.length;

// IMPORT ROAD 
var importroadcount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 1);
});
importroadcount = importroadcount.length;

// EXPORT AIR 
var exportaircount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 2);
});
exportaircount = exportaircount.length;

// EXPORT SEA 
var exportseacount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 4);
});
exportseacount = exportseacount.length;

// EXPORT ROAD 
var exportroadcount = $.grep(json, function(v) {
  return (v.o == 3);
});
exportroadcount = exportroadcount.length;

$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Import', 'Export']
    },

    chart: {
      // Edit chart spacing
      spacingBottom: 15,
      spacingTop: 100,
      spacingLeft: 110,
      spacingRight: 10,

      // Explicitly tell the width and height of a chart
      width: 1000,
      height: 500
    },
    // IMPORT THEN EXPORT
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          style: {
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'AIR',
        data: [importaircount, exportaircount],
        color: 'gray',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }

      }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'SEA',
        data: [importseacount, exportseacount],
        color: 'blue',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'ROAD',
        data: [importroadcount, exportroadcount],
        color: 'green',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }, {
        type: 'pie',
        categories: ['Import', 'Export'],
        data: [{
          name: 'Import',
          y: exportcount,
          color: 'red'
        }, {
          name: 'Export',
          y: importcount,
          color: '#5882FA'
        }],
        center: [30, 80],
        size: 100,
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="bb.js"></script>

<button id="0" class="chartbtn">1 month</button>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 350px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: How can I make it so when I press the 1 month button in my html it only shows data entries that fall between the current data and 1 month ago in my chart.  In my Var json these date that need to be checked if they fall between this date rang are located under the key "P".

Comment: if the date in key "P" is with in the last month show in table and so on. If the data is no withing the last month just ignore everything in that section.

Comment: You can use something like `$.grep(json, function (data) { return (data.P > new Date().getDate() - 30 && data.P < new Date(); });` to get the correct data from your object. Highcharts needs the data to be sorted correctly like this on your array `result.sort(function (a, b) { return a.P == b.P ? 0 : (a.P <  b.P ? -1 : 1); });` Also please note that when you want to have an X axis you have to transform the datetime to a timestamp in microseconds. I'm gonna write an answer as this box is too small to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you'd basically want to achieve right now:

1. You want a button you can click to add one month worth of data (Going for the async route).
2. You want your data transformed in a way that Highcharts can display it correctly.

The only dependencies on this code are JQuery and Highcharts.

**0. Preconditions**

With the code down here I assume there's a `highcharts` variable which contains the Highcharts instance. You should be able to create this one by doing something like this after Highcharts is initialized:

```
var highcharts = $("#container").highcharts();
```

**1. Clickable button**

```
<button id="month">1 month</button>
```

So far the HTML.

```
$( "#month" ).on( "click", function() {
    // All our data transformation logic comes in here
    // Or at least call a function here which does the transform
});
```

So far the button handler.

**2. Data transformation**

The part of transforming the data is a little trickier, but thankfully we got JQuery.

First lets get our data selection from your `json` object:

```
var startDate = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30);
var endDate = new Date();
var dataSelection = $.grep(json, function (data) { 
    return new Date(data.P) > startDate && new Date(data.P) < endDate;
});

// Sort the data based on the datetime. (Highcharts wont do that for you)
var dataSelection = dataSelection.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1);
});

// Now create an array with data we're going to add to highcharts.
var chartLine = [];
$.map(dataSelection, function (d) {
    // First item in the array is the timestamp (in microseconds).
    // Second item is the variable you'd like to get graphed.
        // Chose `o` cuz I think it's nice
    chartLine.push([new Date(d.P).getTime() * 1000, d.o]);
});

// Push the data to the chart.
highcharts.series.addSeries(chartLine);
```

I hope the above is pretty wel self explanatory. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - I get this when I press the button - Uncaught ReferenceError: o is not defined.

Comment: Excuse me, needed to be `d.o` as `o` was supposed to be a variable within an object from your `json` array.

Comment: So replace the o with d.o ?

Comment: I then get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined --- regarding highcharts.series.addSeries(chartLine);

Comment: the `highcharts` variable is empty. Please check it's contents directly after you assign it.

Comment: console.log(chartLine); shows - 
0: Array[2]
0: 0
1: 6

Comment: If you read the text carefully you can learn how to incorporate the code from my answer with your code to achieve what you want. Regarding your earlier comment please check with point 0 from my answer.

Comment: I dont think will work with my data and needs...... could you show it working in a fiddle or snippet please?

Comment: I'll try to write something tonight, if I got some time left.

Comment: That would be amazing if you could. Thank youu

Comment: also when your pushing data to the chart. The pie takes y exportcount and the column takes [importseacount,exportseacount] and were just pushing one set of data in yours?

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#chartbtn1" ).click( "click", function() {

 startDate = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30);
 endDate = new Date();
 importcount  = $.grep(json,function(v){
        return (v.o == 5 || v.o== 6 || v.o==1)&& new Date(v.P) > startDate && new Date(v.P) < endDate;  
    });
importcount = importcount.length;

popchart ();
```

etc ..... (did the same of the rest of my var counts) Works fine